# VPN tunnel over ExpressRoute with Private Peering

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn

Anyone know if we can use ExpressRoute Private peering and establish a site-to-site IPsec/IKE VPN tunnel over ER between our selected on-premises network and Azure VNet using Azure VPN Gateway?

Here is a similar article but it's NOT what I'm looking for e.g. it use microsoft peering, there are two vNets shown etc.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/site-to-site-vpn-over-microsoft-peering

Based on what I know so far, we can only have one type of gateway attached to the VNet so once I have ER gateway attached to my Vnet I can not use the same VNet and attach the Azure VPN Gateway to do s2s encryption.

Is there any other option to achieve my requirement? I believe I have to use network virtual device from Azure Marketplace.

Hoping someone can clarifies this for me ... thanks

Saif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Private peering you will need to use a Network appliance (IaaS).  There are many available in the marketplace.  I have done it with customers using Cisco devices but there are other vendor devices that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Ken.